# what is the difference between operators associativity and order of evaluation in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, operators

What is the difference between operators associativity and order of evaluation?

I  have expected that  operator associativity  is a precedence of operators which in the same group and have  the same precedence, but I cannot understand the difference between operators associativity and order of evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associativity informs the order of evaluation of the components of an expression, but it does not *entirely* define it.

Consider this expression: `a + b + c`. Associativity of `+` is left-to-right, so we know that this is conceptually equivalent to `((a + b) + c)`. What this means is that the expression `a + b` gets evaluated before the addition of that result to `c`. That informs the order of evaluation.

But this *does not* entirely define ordering. That it, it does not mean that `a` or `b` gets evaluated before `c`. It is entirely possible for a compiler to evaluate `c` first, then `a` and then `b`, then `+`ing `a` and `b`, and finally `+`ing that to the result of `c`. Indeed, in C++14, it is possible for a compiler to partially evaluate `c`, then evaluate part of `a`, then some of `b`, then some of `c` etc. That all depends on how complex `a`, `b`, and `c` are.

This is particularly important if one of these is a function call: `a(x + y, z) + b + c`. The compiler can evaluate `x`, then `c`, then `z`, then `y`, then `b`, then `x + y`, then evaluate `a`, then call the result of that evaluation, then adding that to `b`, then adding that to `c`.

Comment: ❤❤That is great, it explained me a lot, thank you

Comment: through your answer.  I have understood that order of eveluation is part of operators associativity And be unexpected who is calculated first I think this only happens in addition and subtraction is thia is true?

Comment: So what i understood that operators associativity determine order of evaluation for operators which  have the same priority in opreator precedence and its in same group but associativity can not entirely determine order of operation because in Addition and subtraction I don't know which one was calculated first

Comment: Did I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

The operator associativity only determines how the operands are associated. In other words, we can say that **how the parenthesis are added to the expression when the precedence of operators are the same**.

Let's take an example. We all know that `2+3*4` will be translated to `2+(3*4)`, not `(2+3)*4`, because the precedence of `*` is higher than `+`. So the parenthesis are added to `*` instead of `+`.

But what happens if the precedence of operators are the same, such as `8/4/2`? Associativity takes parts in it.

Because the associativity of `/` is **left to right**, `8/4/2` will be translated to `(8/4)/2`, not `8/(4/2)`, so we get `1`, not `4`.

Let's take another example: `a+=b+=c`, where `a==100`, `b==10` and `c==1`. Because the associativity of `+=` is **right to left**, the expression `a+=b+=c` will be translated to `a+=(b+=c)`, not `(a+=b)+=c`. So we get `a==111`, `b==11`, `c==1` instead of `a==111`, `b==10`, `c==1`.

But how the associativity(or we say, parenthesis) influence the order of evaluation? You can try this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int &func(int &x){
    cout<<"Func() called by variable "<<&x<<endl;
    return x;
}
int main(){
    int a(8),b(4),c(2);
    cout<<"The address of a is "<<&a<<endl
        <<"The address of b is "<<&b<<endl
        <<"The address of c is "<<&c<<endl<<endl;
    func(a)/(func(b)/func(c));
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code and got the result as follows:

```
The address of a is 0x1013fc04
The address of b is 0x1013fc08
The address of c is 0x1013fc0c

Func() called by variable 0x1013fc04
Func() called by variable 0x1013fc08
Func() called by variable 0x1013fc0c
4
```

In this case, obviously, we find that `func(a)` was computed first, then `func(b)`, and the last is `func(c)`, although we added a parenthesis to `func(b)/func(c)`.

Let's look at another example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        A &operator+(A &a){
            cout<<"A operator+() called by "<<this<<endl;
            return *this;
        }
};
int main(){
    A a,b,c;
    cout<<"The address of a is "<<&a<<endl
        <<"The address of b is "<<&b<<endl
        <<"The address of c is "<<&c<<endl<<endl;
    a+(b+c);
    cout<<endl;
    a+b+c;//According to the association of +, it's equal to (a+b)+c;
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code and got the result as follows:

```
The address of a is 0x100af78d
The address of b is 0x100af78e
The address of c is 0x100af78f

A operator+() called by 0x100af78e
A operator+() called by 0x100af78d

A operator+() called by 0x100af78d
A operator+() called by 0x100af78d
```

Hey, we find that the parenthesis changed the order of evaluation! In `(a+b)+c` the `a+b` is evaluated before `(a+b)+c`; but in `a+(b+c)` the `b+c` is evaluated before `a+(b+c)`.

So how do we understand it?

According to [Order of Evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), (Since C++11)

> The value computations (but not the side effects) of the operands to any operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator (but not its side effects).

we find that the operand will be evaluated before the whole expression. In expression `a+(b+c)`, both `a` and `b+c` are operands, and in expression `b+c` both `b` and `c` are operands. So `b` and `c` are evaluated before `b+c`; `a` and `b+c` are evaluated before `a+(b+c)`. But what's the order of `a`, `b` and `c`? We have no idea.

Let's turn back to `func(8)/(func(4)/func(2))`. As we know, `func(8)` was evaluated first, then `func(4)`, and the last is `func(2)`. Parenthesis doesn't change the order of them, because they are the smallest units in the expression and can't be influenced by the precedence or associativity of operator. But the expression `func(4)/func(2)` is influenced, which makes this `+` evaluated first.

As a result, we can draw this conclusion: the operator precedence/associativity and parenthesis can affect which operator evaluated first, but it can't influence the computing order of smallest units(`func(8)`, and `a`).

Answer (score -1):

In C++, "associativity" refers to the direction in which an operator is applied to its operands, while "order of evaluation" refers to the order in which operands are evaluated. For example, the addition operator (+) has left-to-right associativity, meaning multiple additions in an expression are evaluated from left to right. However, the order of evaluation is not guaranteed to be predictable, and can affect the result of an expression with side effects. Understanding these concepts is important for writing correct and predictable code.